# Google API authorisation doesn't work with Firebase anymore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an app ( in React, but that's not particularly relevant to the question I guess ) using Firebase.

It's quite simple, the client load the google api script

```html
  ...
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then I use this function to "init" it:

```js
function initGoogleAPI() {
    gapi = window.gapi;

    function initClient() {
        // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
        gapi.client
            .init({
                apiKey: "----------_API_KEY_--------- ",
                clientId:
                    "------_CLIENT_ID_-------.apps.googleusercontent.com", //config.google.client_id,
                discoveryDocs: [
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"
                ],
                scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly" // from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
            })
            .then(() => {
                store.state.currentUserProfile = null;
                store.state.authenticated = false;

                // Listen for sign-in state changes.
                gapi.auth2
                    .getAuthInstance()
                    .isSignedIn.listen(updateAuthStatus);

                // Handle the initial sign-in state.
                    updateAuthStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());

            });
    }

    // 1. Load the JavaScript client library.
    gapi.load("client:auth2", initClient);
}
```

And this triggers the updateAuthStatus() function. This function does a bit of secondary checks and setup but basically the point where it breaks now si the signiInWithCredential method call:

```js
function updateAuthStatus() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // we have no auth!
        ...

        var googleUser = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
        var googleProfile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        var isSignedIn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();

        if (isSignedIn) {
            var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
            );
            // we now want to auth in to Firebase with the googleUser credentials
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(user => {
                // do we have a user?
                var hasUser = Boolean(user !== null);

                if (hasUser) {
                    DB.ref("users").child(user.uid).once("value", snap => {
                        var profile = snap.val();
                        console.log(user);
                        if (profile === null) {
                            var payload = {
                                email: user.email,
                                displayName: user.displayName,
                                photoURL: user.photoURL,
                                refreshToken: user.refreshToken,
                                signupDate: new Date().getTime(),
                                uid: user.uid
                            };
                            snap.ref.update(payload).then(e => {
                                store.state.currentUserProfile = payload;
                                store.state.authenticated = hasUser;
                                resolve();
                            });
                        } else {
                            store.state.currentUserProfile = profile;
                            store.state.authenticated = hasUser;
                            resolve();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    resolve(hasUser);
                }
            });
            
        } else {
            store.state.authenticated = false;
            resolve(false);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that when I call the signInWithCredential method I now get this error:

> Error:
>   {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"keyExpired","message":"Bad
>   Request"}],"code":400,"message":"Bad Request"}}

I'm also worried it could have something to do with Firebase / Google Cloud APP keys. Right now the interface and the integrations betweeen the two services are quite a mess in my opinion.

This same code was working and it stopped. How would you debug this?

Comment: You must have set some referrer restrictions on your browser API key. That is why you are getting this error. You need to remove these restrictions in the cloud console.

Comment: Right, it was an authorization issue...
It turned out that the Firebase API key somehow updated itself with the same API key in the google cloud platform.
I tried when as soon as I noticed it and it didn't work.
Now it does.

Everything works now but not understanding why it broke in the first place disturbs me quite a bit